# Fetching Data on Server Component Causes Build Error in NextJS 14

Tags: typescript, next.js13

im trying to fetch products from external API in my app/page.tsx like this:

```
async function getProducts() {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `https://superindo-retail-api.vercel.app/api/products`,
        {
          method: "GET",
          next: {
            revalidate: 5,
          },
        }
      );
      const data = await response.json();
      return data.products;

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return [];
    }
}
```

And then in the Page() component I invoke that function:

```
export default async function Home() {
  var products = await getProducts();
  // ... rest of component
```

when I run npm run build I get the following error:

```
Error occurred prerendering page "/". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11372:11)
 ✓ Generating static pages (9/9)

> Export encountered errors on following paths:
        /page: /
```

Any idea why?

I tried to remove the getProducts() function, and it works. Also I tried to reduce the function to this and it works:

```
async function getProducts() {
  // try {
  //   const response = await fetch(
  //     `https://superindo-retail-api.vercel.app/api/products`,
  //     {
  //       method: "GET",
  //       next: {
  //         revalidate: 5,
  //       },
  //     }
  //   );
  //   const data = await response.json();
  //   return data.products;
  return [];
  // } catch (error) {
  //   console.log(error);
  //   return [];
  // }
}
```

I also tried using mock product data from a local typescript file, but the build process produces same error again:

```
import { Product, products } from "@/lib/data";
async function getProducts() {
  // comments
  return products;
  // comments
}
```

Comment: This code is working fine for me , if you can share your folder structure then it would be better for understand.
can you verify that there in no any client component inside app directory